# Android Pass String form Service to Service?And use at onCreate in Service?

Tags: java, android, string, service

I Have two services.so here I am passing string form one service to another service

Here I used This to pass string value..

```
startService(new Intent(Service_A.this, Service_A.class).putExtra("svdata", url));
```

and this to receive the string

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    MyURL = intent.getExtras().getString("svdata");

    System.out.print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+MyURL+"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

And at onCreate I am starting my webserive with that Url

but the url is missing,

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
   try{
       new MyWebService(ServWeb.this).execute();
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Connect Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

}
```

I am using this `MyWebService()` to get json data with that URL.

But URL is wokring and String in getting. The exact url value, But before that `onCreate()` method is running

But I have given String to `onStartCommand()`

can any one suggest me how to set the string as Url to my service.
or How to add string directly to onCreate. *In Service*

**Update**

My problem is.. 
I am starting Service at `onCreate` I have a Json service it will get json from url. But I am getting `String(url)` form another Service.

To pass String form Service to Service I used
`startService(new Intent(Service_A.this, Service_A.class).putExtra("svdata", url));`

But to Receive that string I need to write `onStartCommand`..

Here I am getting string, but I want to use the same string in `onCreate`...

is there any way to get that string at onCreate...IN SERVICE

Comment: onCreate will get called only once .  So its better you get the value before starting the Service .

Comment: can you update it in answer... hence its a service I am unable to get that .. but how ever the string is passing ...Here I am starting service for every 5 min

Answer (score 0):

Write a SyncManager (singleton class) for handling your service work.

in your oncreate method :
 supply sync credentials like url,user info, etc..

```
 public class SyncService extends IntentService {

     SyncManager syncManager;

     /**
      * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
      *
      * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
      */

     public SyncService(String name) {
      super(name);
     }

     public SyncService() {
      super("SyncService");
     }

     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       syncManager = SyncManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
       syncManager.startSynchronisation();
      }
      /* The service is starting, due to a call to startService() */
     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
     }


     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
     }

    }
```

Comment: But I want to use the string in onCreate .. Because I am running my json service at onCreate... Here the problem Is after starting service-->Oncrete---> onstart command(String...).... But I want Sting--->oncreate..

Comment: you should update your question in a better way then.